# End-of-Session Handling in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember application that requires user authentication on the server side.  Once authenticated (via login), application runs normally.  The application shows a logout button.  Pressing this logout button sends a message to the server, which causes the server to terminate the session, does some clean up, and sends the login page for the client to display.  All this works fine.

But here's the problem: if the user hits the browser's 'back' button after logging off, he will see the app again and can interact with it.  The app can still send messages to the server.  Currently, the server will always respond by sending back the login page when the session is already terminated.  How do I get ember to transition to this login page received from the server?  The fact that users can still get back to a running application (at least on the client side) after logging off would cause some confusion.

What's the recommended method for handling this?  Is there anyway to make the Ember application end when the user hits the logout button?  Maybe just disable the browser's back button when the user logs off (how do you do this in Ember?)?

Answer (score 1):

You can either check in every route if the session is loggedIn or not in activate hook of route like this..

if you are setting a variable `loggedIn` true here is how to do it.

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    if (!loggedIn){
      this.tansitionTo('login');
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to remove totally PostRoute from history you can use [replaceWith](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_replaceWith) rather `transitionTo`.

.or use these for authentication [ember-auth](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/) or [simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have another scenario that's a bit more general: supposed the user leaves his application to do something else without logging off, and in the mean time, session on the server times out.  Now the server will require another login before processing anything sent from the client.  I would like the user to see a login screen if he clicks any button on the screen, regardless whether that click results in a message being sent to the server.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?